# Clean up windows update backup and install files

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, windows-server-2003

I have a Server 2003 box and noticed the Windows directory is 4 gigs. I guess that's primarily Windows updates. Is it possible to clean up these updates?

As a side note, it would be cool to do this on my XP boxes if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay away from the `winsxs` folder. You can kill all the ones starting with a $ and using NTFS compression.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice not to touch the Windows directory, except for the directory containing temporary files : `C:\Windows\Temp`. You can delete all files here and ignore all error messages about files in use.

In fact, it's good practice to move this temporary directory out of the Windows directory. One does that by Control Panel / System / Advanced system settings / Environment Variables. Set the values of TEMP and TMP for both User and System.